# Единая точка входа

Tags: php

Вопрос касаемо концепции единой точки входа в web-приложении: ajax запросы необходимо отправлять также в эту точку, или их желательно обрабатывать отдельно? Какие дополнительные трудности могут возникнут в дальнейшем если обрабатывать их отдельно?
И второй вопрос: если писать эту единую точку входа средствами ООП, желательно ли уходить в сторону static ф-й и забивать на объекты? (конечно же не всегда).

Comment: С какой целью интересуешься? С фреймворками знакомство было? И каким образом, к примеру, аякс запросы обрабатывать отдельно от единой точки входа в приложение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ИМХО:

1) Единая точка входа это механизм, которые уже доказал свою практичность.

2) Что касается вопроса про объекты и статические функции. Я его до конца не понял... Вообще это все описано в MVC. В любом фреймворке есть роутинг, который сопоставляет запрос с тем или иным контроллером. И все это разумеется объекты.

3) AJAX-запросы тоже надо обрабатывать через единоую точку входа, т.к. это все части одной системы.